# Eigenvalues of $B = u v^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find all the eigenvalues of $B= u v^t$ where $u,v$ are column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

---

With some trick $\det(I + B) = 1 + \operatorname{tr}(B)$ [This is due to rank $B$ is $1$], I can do
\begin{align}
\det(\lambda I -B) = \lambda^m \det(I - \lambda^{-1} B) = \lambda^m \left( 1  + \operatorname{tr}(-\lambda^{-1}B)\right) = \lambda^m \left(1 - \lambda^{-1} \operatorname{tr}(B) \right) = \lambda^m \left(1-\lambda^{-1} \lambda \right) =0?
\end{align}
It seems this does not that useful.

Comment: Rank one: there is one nonzero eigenvalue all the others are zero.  The nonzero eigenvalue is $\text{tr}\; B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $v^tu \in \Bbb{R}$ so
$$B^2 - (v^t u)B = (uv^t)(uv^t)  - (v^tu)(uv^t) = u(v^tu)v^t  - (v^tu)(uv^t) = (v^tu)(uv^t) - (v^tu)(uv^t) = 0.$$
Hence the polynomial $x^2 - (v^tu)x = x(x-v^tu)$ annihilates $B$ and hence the eingenvalues are contained in its zeroes: $0$ and $v^tu$.

Both are indeed eigenvalues. $B$ has rank $1$ so it clearly noninvertible and hence $0$ is an eigenvalue. On the other hand
$$(uv^t)u = u(v^tu) = (v^tu)u$$
so $v^tu$ is also an eigenvalue. Note that $\operatorname{Tr} B = v^tu$ since
$$\operatorname{Tr} B = \operatorname{Tr}(uv^t) = \operatorname{Tr}(v^tu) = v^tu.$$

Comment: I have a question on the last step of $$(uv^t)u = u(v^tu) = (v^tu)u$$, What is the reason for the last equality?

Comment: @phy_math Note that $v^tu \in \Bbb{R}$ so we can pull it before the vector $u$.